WordPress function for displaying users that clicked a button
I try to display users on a custom post type that clicked a button. I‘ve created this function.
This is the code to add the button
<?php
// Display the post content
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        the_content();
        
        // Add a form with a button for tracking user clicks
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $nonce = wp_create_nonce('track_button_click');
            ?>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="track_button_click_nonce" value="<?php echo esc_attr($nonce); ?>">
                <button type="submit" name="track_button_click">Click me!</button>
            </form>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>

This is the function to handle the form submission when users click the button.
function handle_button_click() {
    if (isset($_POST['track_button_click'])) {
        // Verify nonce
        if (isset($_POST['track_button_click_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['track_button_click_nonce'], 'track_button_click')) {
            // Get current user ID
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            // Add user ID to a secure user meta key (custom database table or secure storage method)
            $clicked_users = get_option('clicked_users', array());
            if (!in_array($user_id, $clicked_users)) {
                $clicked_users[] = $user_id;
                update_option('clicked_users', $clicked_users);
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'handle_button_click');

And this is the function to display the users list.
function display_clicked_users() {
    $clicked_users = get_option('clicked_users', array());

    if (!empty($clicked_users)) {
        echo '<h2>Users who clicked the button:</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($clicked_users as $user_id) {
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            if ($user_info) {
                echo '<li>' . esc_html($user_info->display_name) . '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>No users have clicked the button yet.</p>';
    }
}

The template tag.
display_clicked_users();

If I implement these lines of code it seems working at first sight. But in the end nothing happens when the button is clicked. The list with all users and the date and time they clicked on the button doesn't appear.

Is the data stored in the database? You can debug your code by following each action with logs like error_log('Button was clicked'); Then you can see where your code is stuck. Don't forget to enable wp_debug!
